# Replace Variables from static template-file with PHP and output to user agent

Tags: php, variables, replace, parameters

For automated installation of linux machines I use answer-files with virt-install

```
--extra-args "auto=true url=http://answerfilewebserver.mydomain/$servername hostname=$servername.localdomain"
```

where url is the place of the answer-file.
Until now, I used a static answer-file, because it didn't contain host-specific data

In a special case i need the servername in an answer-file, at the moment i use static files.

```
postfix postfix/mailname string myserver1.localdomain
```

would result in

```
postfix postfix/mailname string $servername.localdomain
```

i need a small and simple solution that parses the template file with $servername in it:

```
http://.../answerfile.php?servername=myserver1
```

and outputs the the content of the template with the variable replaced $servername -> myserver1

I searched on google and here, but didn't find a solution, maybe because I am not a native English speaker and didn't use the right search phrases.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Thank you very much

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Comment: at the moment I dont use any code, I am right at the beginning. I asked the question, because there is certainly already a solution and I have not found it

Comment: How is PHP related to this?

Comment: you are right, it can be done with other programming languages too. but php is easy to understand for me

Comment: This is cli though isn't it? Your question is very vague there is not a lot of detail that helps solve an issue.

Comment: I was searching for an existing solution. If i would write it from scratch, i would use php (as a apache module or fcgid), extract the parameter from url, load the template file, replace the variable with the parameter-value and send the result back to the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i wrote it by myself:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$servername = htmlspecialchars($_GET["servername"]);
$path_to_file = '/var/www/preseed.template';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace("%%servername%%", $servername ,$file_contents);
print_r ($file_contents);
?>
```